# How to change frame rate of MJPEG segments with/without re-encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to record segments using a webcam and save these segments with a lower fps. I've tried this command, but it keeps giving me an error:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -video_size 800x600 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 -r 10 -strict -2 test_%04d.avi
```

The errors I get is:

```
[segment @ 0x15bf0e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 86, current: 73; changing to 87. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0x15bf0e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 87, current: 74; changing to 88. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[segment @ 0x15bf0e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 88, current: 75; changing to 89. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Anyone know how to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

It's a *warning,* not an error (if it would be an error, FFmpeg would abort).

“Non-monotonous DTS” means that the DTS (Display Time Stamp) of some frame *is less than* the DTS of the *previous frame.*

This situation may cause many problems (with playback, seeking, etc.), so 
FFmpeg fixes timestamps by rewriting some of them.

Here are your 3 warning messages:

> ```
> [...] Non-monotonous DTS ... ; previous: 86, current: 73; changing to 87. This may ...
> [...] Non-monotonous DTS ... ; previous: 87, current: 74; changing to 88. This may ...
> [...] Non-monotonous DTS ... ; previous: 88, current: 75; changing to 89. This may ...
> ```

in a graphical form:
[image]